# How to divide width of parent div between child divs(one auto size and one fixed)?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains two child divs.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Now the constraints are that

1. parent div can take any width
2. child1+child2 width equal to width of parent
3. child1 should maintain aspect ratio (width/height) 1.6
4. child2 will always have fixed width say 100px and height equal to child1
5. not using html5 and css3

Comment: What have you currently tried? Looks like you're copying over a homework question without putting in any prior research.

Comment: Seriously now. With constraint 3, your only choice is to use JS. There is no pure HTML+CSS that can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
Obviously this is something which is not posible usign pure HTML+CSS code. You will have to get help of JS code. So I have got it worked by jQuery.

```
#parent{
    width:500px;
    background:#000;
}
#child1{
    background:#ff0000;
    float:left;
}
#child2{
    background:#0000ff;
    float:left;
}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#child1").width($("#parent").width()-100);
    $("#child2").width($("#parent").width()-$("#child1").width());
    $("#child1").height($("#child1").width()*6);
    $("#child2").height($("#child1").height());
    alert($("#child1").width());
    alert($("#child2").width());
    alert($("#child1").height());
    alert($("#child2").height());
});
</script>

<body>
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
</body>
```